# Can Distinct be expressed using so-called embedded query rather than a method call

Tags: linq

given the following code:

```
string[]  colors = {"red","green","blue","red","green","blue"};
var distinctColors = (from c in colors select c).Distinct();
distinctColors.Dump();
```

Is it possible to fold the call `.Distinct()` into the embedded query syntax?

something like int T-SQL

```
select distinct color from TableofColors
```

Comment: By the way, it's called Query Comprehension Syntax.

Comment: @SLaks: Or just "query expressions" as per section 7.15 of the spec.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C#'s query expression syntax doesn't include "distinct". VB's does, however - for example, from the [MSDN docs for VB's Distinct clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384803.aspx):

```
// VB
Dim customerOrders = From cust In customers, ord In orders _
                     Where cust.CustomerID = ord.CustomerID _
                     Select cust.CompanyName, ord.OrderDate _
                     Distinct
```

The C# equivalent would have to explicitly call `Distinct()` in dot notation.

However, your example can still be simplified:

```
string[]  colors = {"red","green","blue","red","green","blue"};
var distinctColors = colors.Distinct();
distinctColors.Dump();
```

Don't think you *have* to use query expressions to use LINQ :)

Answer (score 2):

There's no distinct embedded query syntax in C# as far as I'm aware. This is as close as it gets:

```
var distinctColors = (from color in colors
                      select color).Distinct()
```

Answer (score 1):

Query comprehension syntax does not support the `Distinct` method.

In your case, you could simply write `colors.Distinct()`; you're not doing anything with the query expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
var dis = from c in colors
   group c by c;

foreach (var cVal in dis)
   {
      string s = cVal.Key;
   }
```

Comment: This will return an `IEnmerable<IGrouping<String>>`, not an `IEnumerable<String>`.

Comment: You should write `from c in colors group c by c into c select c.Key`.  Also, it'll probably be a bit slower than `Distinct`.

Comment: SLaks. Do you have any stats proving group by slower thatn distinct?

Comment: No; that's why I said _probably_.

Comment: I just tried it in LINQPad using the array in the question; `Distinct` was roughly twice as fast.